# Installing exscript in Linux

Tags: python, linux, fedora, paramiko

I've been trying to install exscript on two different Linux machines without much success. I've tried utilizing the Installation guide [here](https://github.com/knipknap/exscript/wiki/Installation-Guide) , making sure I have python-crypto, paramiko, Python setuptools, etc. Then I do a make install on exscript, and everything looks normal. However, I try to pull up the exscript help page and:

```
root@slave1 exscript# exscript --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/exscript", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Exscript==v2.1.365-g7b15387
```

That happens. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did this solve your issue ? https://github.com/knipknap/exscript/issues/2

Comment: Installing it with `pip` took care of all dependencies and resulted on a working `exscript`. Try `yum install python-pip` followed by `pip install https://github.com/knipknap/exscript/tarball/master`.